# How to disable native browser tooltip with bootstrap4 tooltip

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-4, font-awesome-5

The following code shows both the bootstrap tooltip and the native title-attribute tooltip:

```
This is my text. 
<i class="far fa-question-circle" data-toggle="tooltip" title="This is my tooltip."></i> 
$(function () {
  $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip()
})
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qfcs9azv/4/)

How can I *not* show the native title-attribute of Fontawesome 5's icon-svg, so only the Bootstrap-tooltip is shown?

Comment: Remove `title="This is my tooltip."` and you're done. What's the matter?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can try following HTML

```
This is my text. <i class="far fa-question-circle" data-toggle="tooltip" data-title="This is my tooltip."></i>
```

Since the default nature of browser is difficult to override and may cause unexpected behavior we can choose alternative way to solve the issue

The Bootstrap 4 tool-tip can also show tool tip if the attribute is prefixed with `data`. so you can replace `title` attribute with `data-title`

Here is a working fiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/samuelj90/qfcs9azv/18/

Answer (score 1):

I had issues with the `data-title` from the answers above, instead I had to use the `data-original-title`. You can set this property using the `attr` function from jQuery or directly into the DOM.

**HTML:**

```
This is my text. 
<i class="far fa-question-circle" data-toggle="tooltip"></i>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
$(function () {
    //Initialize the Bootstrap tooltip
    $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();

    //Force the Tooltip title change at run time
    $('.fa-question-circle').attr('data-original-title', "This is my tooltip.");
})
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jrod336/908u17sq/7/)

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve by `title` attribute so don't use directly `data-title` or `data-original-title` attribute because of if we are targeting SEO friendly page then need to write well title text. So This is not `Bootstrap4` tooltip issue so the main reason is that when created `svg` tag by `fontawesome` script for icon then its wrapping `title="hello" attribute` to `<title>hello<title> tag` inside svg tag.
So we can remove `title` tag by `show.bs.tooltip` event.
Doc: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/components/tooltips/#events

```js
$(function () {
  $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
});
$(function () {
  $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').on('show.bs.tooltip', function (e) {
   //Remove title tag from inside created svg tag
   $(this).find('title').remove();
 });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.6/js/all.js"></script>


<div class="container py-4">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4">
     This is my text. <i class="far fa-question-circle" data-toggle="tooltip" title="This is my tooltip."></i>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```